# Windows Virtual PC, multi-core possible?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode, multi-core, hardware-virtualization

I have a PC based on a "Intel i7 975". My OS is "Win7 Ultimate 64bit", and I have installed "Windows Virtual PC" + "XP Mode". My problem is that only ONE core is virtualized, so, can I virtualize two of my four cores? Thanks!

Comment: This is very easy to do with VMplayer and Virtual box.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a win XP license? If you have one, I suggest you to use [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) which can be highly customized at this point.
If not, it may be possible to set the vm's process two more than one core using the task manager.